# solving first order ode for boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y' = 1/B -1/x^2 $
B.V are
  $y(1) = 0 , y(2) = A $

solution I think is $ y = x/B + k + 1/x $

How do I solve it for given boundary conditions ?

Comment: Could you explain what is k?

Comment: Are you sure about $1/x^x$ ?

Comment: I corrected it $1/x^2$

Comment: Are you sure it is $y(0)=0$?

Comment: $ y(1) = 0 $  I am sorry about that. Fixed it too.

Comment: You wrote $y(1)=0$ and $y(1)=A$. So, $A=0$ ?

Comment: I am sorry again. Fixed it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general solution $\quad  y = \frac{x}{B} + k + \frac{1}{x} \quad$ is correct.

HINT :

$\begin{cases}
y(1) = 0 =\frac{1}{B} + k + \frac{1}{1}\\
y(2) = A = \frac{2}{B} + k + \frac{1}{2} 
\end{cases}\qquad$
To be solved for $\frac{1}{B}$ and $k\quad$ (Linear system).